# Attempting to apply a 'blur' filter to a bmp for CS50 pset4, and the output image is much darker

Tags: c, image, algorithm, blur, cs50

This is the output and input image that my code generates: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiNJe.jpg

The following code is for the blur function, all the supporting code is untouched from pset4.

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height] [width])
{
RGBTRIPLE newImage[height][width];

for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
{
    for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
    {
        BYTE redAvg = 0;
        BYTE greenAvg = 0;
        BYTE blueAvg = 0;
        BYTE count = 0;

        for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
        {
            for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++)
            {
                int h_1 = h + y;
                int w_1 = w + x;

                if (h_1 >= 0 && h_1 < height && w_1 >= 0 && w_1 < width)
                {
                    count++;
                    redAvg += image[h_1][w_1].rgbtRed;
                    greenAvg += image[h_1][w_1].rgbtGreen;
                    blueAvg += image[h_1][w_1].rgbtBlue;
                }
            }
        }
        newImage[h][w].rgbtRed = redAvg/count;
        newImage[h][w].rgbtGreen = greenAvg/count;
        newImage[h][w].rgbtBlue = blueAvg/count;
    }
}
for (int x = 0; x < height; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y <width; y++)
    {
        image[x][y] = newImage[x][y];
    }
}
return;
}
```

Comment: Arithmetic overflow is your enemy. Specifically, the values in `redAvg`, `greenAvg` and `blueAvg` are very likely overflowing a `BYTE`.

Comment: Thank you so much man! I got it working, overflow was the problem.